# Failed to create sample database (SP2010)

Tags: installation

Env:
OS: Win2008 R2 (running inside VirtualBox)
RAM: 2GB
Installed all available Windows Updates

My fresh SP2010 prerequisites and installation went well.  Later while running the SharePoint Product Configuration for the first time, at Step# 8, while creating Sample Database, it gave me this error:

http://cid-f72f4bb11ec94af8.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/pub-scrshots/SP2010-Configuration-Wizard-Failed-Step8.png

[image: Config wizard error]

Event Viewer contains this entry:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard
Date:          2/9/2010 6:03:01 PM
Event ID:      104
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SP2010
Description:
Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56)
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.Get(String name)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.get_Client()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.GetServiceBinding(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.GetChannelFactory(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.ProvisionServiceApplicationsAndProxies()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">104</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-02-09T12:33:01.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1934</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SP2010</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56)
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56) ---&gt; System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebClients\Profile\client.config line 56)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object&amp; result, Object&amp; resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object&amp; result, Object&amp; resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.Get(String name)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.get_Client()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.GetServiceBinding(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.GetChannelFactory(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.ProvisionServiceApplicationsAndProxies()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_2_9_2010_17_44_33_362_561052642.log, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again.
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the WCF hotfix [KB976462](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976462). [Download it here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166231)...

And please add some more memory to your virtual host, 2GB is bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks Wictor. I downloaded and installed this patch.  As I don't have much physical RAM, i increased the Virtual Memory.  After this I re-ran the Configuration Wizard and it went through (although took long time).  Thanks for your help.